# Read a lot of data from DB and print in a GridView

Tags: c#, database, linq, gridview

I am reading a huge amount of data from a SQL Server database (approx. 2.000.000 entries) and I want to print it to the end-user in a winforms `GridView`.

**First Approach**

First idea was using `SQLDataReader` which normally doesn't take too much time to read from tables with aound 200.000 entries. But uses too much memory (and time !) in the case above.

**Actual Solution**

The actual solution used is reading from the database through `LINQ` (`dbml` file) which is fine because it plugs the components directly to the DB server. It loads data *on-the-fly*, which is really great.

**Problems**

The problems are :

- When I plug my grid view to the `FeedBack Source`, it seemed to me that I couldn't read the columns of my grid through code.

This is for plugging my `LookUpSearchEdit` to the source :

```
slueTest.Properties.DataSource = lifsTest; // This is the LinqInstantFeedbackSource
gvTest.PopulateColumns();
```

When I do :

```
gv.Columns["FirstColumn"] // "FirstColumn" is the name of the field in the LINQ Class (and in the DB)
```

It raises an exception ...

- The data in the `FeedBackSource` is not accessible at all ...)
- I lost all the features of the `LookUpSearchEdit` and I think it is because the data is read *on-the-fly* (sorting, searching, etc.).

**Questions**

Am I doing this right ? Or is there a better way to print a lot of data from a DB without consuming lots of memory / time?

Comment: What kind of user can read 200,000 rows ?

Comment: Users in the financial industry :) (+ algorithms)

Comment: How do you display 200k rows? you have any sort of pagination ?

Comment: Algorithms don't need a grid view and users should never have to scroll through 200k rows, that would be nuts. Would it not be sensible to better filter data prior to displaying it?

Comment: You are right guys, this is nonsense at all. What I'm about to do is showing to the user a filtering textbox and I'll execute a `TOP 500` request according to the filter specified. That's the best choice I think ..